# Create JSON instance from JSON schema

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsonschema

Hi I'm trying to create JSON instance from a JSON schema.

Typescript answer is appreciated, but appreciate any answers.

Below the the sample-schema.json file. I want to create a function to convert a schema to a schema instance.

Ex: sample-schema.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "first_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "last_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "street_1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "street_2": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "city": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "state": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "AL",
            "AK",
            "AS"
          ]
        },
        "zip_code": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "birthday": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "notes": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "last_name"
  ]
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
  "first_name": "",
  "last_name": "",
  "last_name": "",
  "address": {
    "street_1": "",
    "street_2": "",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "zip_code": ""
  },
  "birthday": "",
  "notes": ""
}
```

On calling the function, by passing the schema it has to generate the JSON instance. I searched on Google but all the results are from JSON *to* JSON schema.

Comment: A cursory glance around the internet seems to indicate you'll likely need to write something yourself if you want to do it from JavaScript. I found a Java tool that could do it, but no JavaScript library you could pull in yourself.

Comment: If you have any source, kindly provide me. Any language will try to modify to my style.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the javascript from this [json-schema-filter](https://github.com/alank64/json-schema-filter)

Answer (score -1):

fetch the value of the `sampleSchema` and use the javascript `JSON.parse(sampleSchema)` method.

Comment: Care to elaborate? Your answer does not mention which library or framework it refers to.